# Filter search based on list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Again, probably another noob django question. I have these two models in my django app

```
#models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Groups)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.question)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    correct = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.answer)
```

I also have a view which interacts with both these models

```
#views.py
def test_detail(request, pk):
    test = get_object_or_404(Test, pk=pk)
    questions = Question.objects.values('id', 'question').filter(test_id=pk).order_by('?')
    answers = Answer.objects.values('answer').filter(question_id__in=list(questions))
    return render(request, 'site/test.html', {'test': test, 'questions': questions, 'answers': answers})
```

'questions' is a list of Question objects which all have an id. That id is also a foreign key in Answer. What I'm trying to do is get all the Answer objects which have the same id as any id in the list 'question',

However, this way throws up a `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'`

Can anyone help point me towards what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you not just filter by `question__in = questions`?

Comment: You want to get a list of answers that have the same id as a question? that sounds like a strange thing to do.... more likely, you're looking for `Question.objects.filter(test_id=pk).prefetch_related('answer')`

Comment: `list(questions)` is a list of `Question` objects, not `Question.id`. Use list comprehension like `[q.id for q in questions]` to get a list of ids from questions.

Comment: @kicker86 general rule of thumb is not to use python iteration for  database queries. Something like comment above is way much more efficient.

Comment: @kicker86 - `list(questions)` is a list of dictionaries since the op uses `values`